# Twelve friends born on month ends

Tags: logical-deduction, seasonal, time

Twelve close friends were born on the last dates of their respective birth months. Fascinatingly, their birth months are different.

---

On 30th June 2023, all twelve of them had gathered for the birthday party of one of them who turned 30.

On that particular day, this was the statistic:

| Age | Number of friends |
| --- | --- |
| 28 | 1 |
| 29 | 2 |
| 30 | 7 |
| 31 | 2 |

---

One of them noticed something and said:

> *On the day we all gather for my birthday party, our ages will be the same as our respective birth dates!*

**On which day (Date, Month and Year) will that unique birthday party be?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the date of the party, the ages will be either

28, 4x30, 7x31, or
29, 4x30, 7x31.

Comparing these against the statistics from June 30th, we'll need

- exactly 5 more months with 31 days, each transforming a 30 into a 31
- exactly 2 more months with 30 days, each transforming a 29 into a 30
- possibly 1 more month with 29 days.

Counting ahead with July (31), August (31), September(30), October (31), November (30), December (31) and January (31), we have reached the exact requirements.

So the party is on

> **January 31st, 2024**

because although that year *is* indeed a leap year, the year 29 years earlier isn't, so the person born in February cannot have been born on the 29th.